# How to save an image after using vintage.js jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, html, jquery-plugins

I am currently using the [vintage.js plugin](https://github.com/rendro/vintageJS) to add some effects to an app.

I am creating but I need to know how can I save the images after adding the effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to save the canvas created by vintage.js to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am actually starting with jQuery could you be a littble more specific? thanks! I mean where do i need to find the canvas if i use vintage.js thanks again!

Comment: I ended up using this instead (http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/), but thanks for the tip! ;)

Comment: I ended up using what i found on this link permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/ :)